# For two sets A and B, prove or disprove each of the following: A is a subset of B and B is a subset of A

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid x = 6a + 4,a\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}\}$ and $B = \{y\in\mathbb{Z} \mid y = 18b - 2, b\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}\}$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ represents the set of positive integers.

Prove or disprove the following statements:

a) $A\subseteq B$

b) $B\subseteq A$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Now, for a set $A$ to be a subset of set $B$, the set $B$ would have to contain all elements of $A$.

So, to disprove this, could use just use an example like $a = 1$ where $x = 6(1) + 4 = 10$ and show that $y = 18b - 2$ cannot equal $10$ when be is a positive integer?  I'm not sure if this is correct or if you could also do this for part b.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint1: does $4\in A$ ? $\in B$ ? Hint2: can you write $18b-2=6a+4$ for some $a=f(b)$ ?

Comment: Right.  There are many ways to show that a) is false, but it suffices to find just one $x\in A$ (e.g. $x=10$) which is provably not in $B$ (E.g. $y\in B\implies y\ge 18(1)-2>10). $ F0r b)  observe that $x\in A\iff 2\le (x+2)/6\in\Bbb Z^+$ while $y\in B\iff  1\le (y+2)/18\in \Bbb Z^+\implies 3\le (y+2)/6\implies y\in A.$

Comment: " I'm not sure if this is correct or if you could also do this for part b." You *could* if you could find a counterexample.  But $18\cdot 1-2 = 16 = 6\cdot 2 + 4$ and $18\cdot 2 -2= 34 = 6\cdot 5 + 4$.  So if you want to find a counterexample it's going to requires something more than trial and error?  Who do you think you will find a counter-example (if that is what you want to do)?

Comment: A single counterexample is always enough to disprove a statement. All examples must be taken (i.e. the proof must consider every possible example) to prove a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we don't know the answer we can try to prove it and see what occurs.  We may get a proof or we may find a that we don't have sufficient reasons to say it is true and we may get the conditions that may lead to a counterexample.

To prove $A\subset B$ we have to show that for ever $6a + 4\in A$ there is a $b$ so that $18b - 2= 6a+4$.  SO let's try to find that $b$.

If that is so then $18b = 6a +6$ and $b = \frac {6a + 6}{18} = \frac {a+1}3$.

But $\frac {a+1}3$ need not be a whole number.

So we failed!  Boo-hoo!

BUT THAT'S OKAY.

Since $b= \frac {a+1}3$ need not be an integer and *could* **FAIL** to be an integer we know it is not an subset and we have a method to find counter-examples.

Let $a$ be so that $\frac {a+1}3$ is *not* an integer.  Ex. $a=1,2,4,5,7,...etc$ and $6a + 4 = 10,16,28,34,46, ....etc$ will never have an integer $b$ so that $18b-2$.

So $A \not \subset B$.

......

On the other hand to prove $B\subset A$ we must show that for every $18b-2\in B$ there is a $6a + 4\in A$ so that $18b-2 = 6a + 4$.  So let's try to find that $a$.

But this time when we try to find that $a$ we get:  $6a = 18b - 6$ so $a =\frac {18b-6}3 = 3b -1$.  But that *is* always an integer.

Oh, no!  We *didn't* fail!  SO we can't find a counter-example and we can't prove $B\not\subset A$!  Boo... hoo?

Wait.  We showed it is always true so .... we *did* prove $B\subset A$.

SO that's that.  If $18b - 2 \in B$ then $6[3b-1] + 4 = 18b -2$ and $6[3b-1]+4\in A$.

So $B\subset A$.

Comment: Love the language in this answer; takes it to the basics

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiastic and simple answer! @fleablood